# VSCode Extension Development debugger is completely gone

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I've been working on a couple Visual Studio Code extensions (with TypeScript). The first 2 extensions launched and debugged fine. Though, the third extension I created had a weird behavior, as the debugger behaved differently than before.

That's until I noticed Visual Studio Code wasn't debugging with the debugger I was using, which, if I remember correctly, was just called **VSCode Extension Development**. All of a sudden, this debugger kind just disappeared from the list and now I'm having trouble getting it back. Instead, VSCode quietly used Node.js as the debugger. Please look at the image below - there's no "VSCode Extension Development" under "Select Debugger", which was included in the list before:
[image]

What should I do to get VSCode Extension Development extension debugger back and then debug my extension with it? I don't use Node.js to debug VSCode extensions.

Additional debugging information:

- Attempting to restart VSCode does not yield any changes (e.g. the debugger is still not on the list),
- The code is the default template created by `yo` VSCode Extension Generator,
- To create this extension, I've done everything I did before: I entered `yo code` into the command prompt. Selected TypeScript. Gave it a name/identifier/description. This is not a Webpack bundle or a Git repository. The package manager is NPM (Node.js Package Manager).
- I did not change any file, like files from the `.vscode` folder, project.json, etc. All I did was built the source code by typing `tsc -p ./` into the command prompt, and then ran it. The result was in the `out` folder, as usual.

Any help would be appreciated.

## Edit

Had to reinstall VSCode, and before installing, deleted AppData\Roaming\Code and %UserProfile%.vscode. Solved the problem, the debugger just appeared on the list 2 minutes or so after (so there is some delay).

Comment: The debug profiles are all in `.vscode/launch.json`. Review its current contents and compare to another extension you worked on.

Comment: I never had to select a debugger for extension development, I use the standard launch config for extensions

Comment: @LexLi I've took a look, they were identical. Then I opened an extension that worked before, it turns out the VSCode Extension Development debugger is completely gone.

Comment: When something like that happens, reinstalling VS Code is inevitable.